Use of undeclared identifier 'YMMConfiguration': Unknown type name 'YMMConfiguration'
I have created an app in React Native. I have used Appmetrica for analytics and currently added just one App Open event in the app. I trying to Build the app in for iOS in xCode but when I Archive the Project it gives this error.
Unknown type name 'YMMConfiguration'
Use of undeclared identifier 'YMMConfiguration'
This is my AppDelegate.mm
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <YandexMobileMetrica/YandexMobileMetrica.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSString *apiKey = @"MY_API_KEY";
  YMMConfiguration *configuration = [[YMMConfiguration alloc] initWithApiKey:apiKey];
  [YMMYandexMetrica activateWithConfiguration:configuration];
  
  self.moduleName = @"CrazyHorse";
  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self bundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end


